# How can i change bar width of progressbar?

Tags: css, javafx

I customized `porgressbar` using css but when i used `-fx-pref-width` for `.bar` it did not work.This is my css :

```
.super-fx-progress-bar {

    -fx-background-color: transparent;

}

.super-fx-progress-bar .track{

    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-border-radius:20;
    -fx-background-radius:20;

}

.super-fx-progress-bar .bar { 

    -fx-background-color: #0057e7,transparent,#6666ff;
    -fx-background-insets: 1 1 1 3, 1 1 1 1, 1 1 2 3; 
    -fx-border-radius:20;
    -fx-background-radius:20;
    -fx-pref-width:2

     /*What should i add to minimize width of bar when its value is indeterminated*/

}
```

Comment: "did not work?" could you add all required code so anyone can test it and give more details on how it "did not work?"

Comment: Can you explain more what do you want exactly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding  :

```
-fx-indeterminate-bar-length:value;
```

in `progressbar` class (you used `.super-fx-progress-bar`) :

I did this to show the differents results :

**First style :**

```
.super-fx-progress-bar {

    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-indeterminate-bar-animation-time:1.0;
    -fx-indeterminate-bar-flip:true;
    -fx-indeterminate-bar-escape:true;
    -fx-indeterminate-bar-length:20;
    -fx-min-height:5;


}
```

**Second style :**

```
.super-fx-progress-bar {

    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-indeterminate-bar-animation-time:1.0;
    -fx-indeterminate-bar-flip:true;
    -fx-indeterminate-bar-escape:true;
    -fx-indeterminate-bar-length:60;
    -fx-min-height:5;


}
```

[image: See the results]